# Is this a bug of BoundingRegion?

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, mesh

```
pts={{-212.5293731689453`,30.075761795043945`,132.3474884033203`},{-198.16456604003906`,30.075759887695312`,136.6664276123047`},{-199.60421752929688`,30.075759887695312`,141.45468139648438`},{-198.28517150878906`,46.827518463134766`,136.63018798828125`},{-212.053955078125`,32.07554626464844`,137.71153259277344`},{-213.96902465820312`,30.075759887695312`,137.1357421875`},{-201.51953125`,32.07575988769531`,140.8788299560547`},{-199.95616149902344`,48.01850509643555`,141.34889221191406`},{-200.0798797607422`,32.07575988769531`,136.090576171875`},{-210.61431884765625`,32.07554626464844`,132.9232635498047`},{-210.51858520507812`,46.44626998901367`,132.95205688476562`},{-211.76150512695312`,47.40089416503906`,137.7994842529297`},{-213.84841918945312`,46.82754898071289`,137.17201232910156`},{-212.34165954589844`,47.13450241088867`,132.40394592285156`},{-212.71707153320312`,49.53857421875`,137.51217651367188`},{-210.71690368652344`,50.3234977722168`,132.8924560546875`},{-210.6386260986328`,51.623714447021484`,138.1370849609375`},{-209.48919677734375`,49.93276596069336`,138.48268127441406`},{-209.2018280029297`,49.03960037231445`,133.3479766845703`},{-206.81231689453125`,50.421024322509766`,134.06640625`},{-206.02227783203125`,50.63017272949219`,139.52505493164062`},{-206.78662109375`,52.61262130737305`,139.2952423095703`},{-204.37022399902344`,52.513790130615234`,134.80064392089844`},{-202.93466186523438`,51.623748779296875`,140.453369140625`},{-207.51675415039062`,52.32311248779297`,133.8546142578125`},{-199.41650390625`,49.53857421875`,136.2900390625`},{-201.51145935058594`,51.57661819458008`,135.66017150878906`},{-202.9318084716797`,49.0469970703125`,140.45423889160156`},{-203.8778533935547`,50.4571647644043`,134.9486846923828`},{-201.30931091308594`,48.843685150146484`,135.720947265625`},{-201.615234375`,46.458553314208984`,140.8500518798828`},{-200.2099609375`,46.49541091918945`,136.0514678955078`}};

bounding=BoundingRegion[#,"MinOrientedCuboid"]&@pts
Parallelepiped[{-199.604,30.0758,141.455},{{0.,-3.21323*10^-6,9.09495*10^-13},{-14.3648,-1.30589*10^-6,-4.31895},{1.43966,-1.30589*10^-6,-4.78829}}]
Graphics3D[bounding]
```

You can see the mesh's bounding nearly becomes a 2d rectangle

What's the problem of first two points?

Mma 12.0 on Mac

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.5], bounding}, Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], 
  Point[pts]}]` highlights the failure. `BoundingRegion[pts, "MinCuboid"]` works as expected. Recommend that you contact [`support`](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=feedback)

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can perform a rigid transform on your points, then perform the inverse on the bounding region.

```
rot = RotationTransform[π, {0, 0, 1}];

cuboid = InverseFunction[rot] @ BoundingRegion[rot @ pts, "MinOrientedCuboid"];

Graphics3D[{
  {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts]},
  {Opacity[.3], cuboid}
}]
```

[image]

Comment: I found I can use nearly 2 Degree, ie rot = RotationTransform[2 Degree, {0, 0, 1}];  But failed in  rot = RotationTransform[1 Degree, {0, 0, 1}];