# Why BoundingRegion so weak in such cases?

Tags: regions, mesh

Each time, when I use `FastCylinder` option in `BoundingRegion`, I'll get this kind result. This problem lasts for many years, since BoundingRegion was introduced in year 2016.

```
mesh=MeshRegion[List[List[-34109.07,-26862.032,10242.804],List[-32567.932,-26555.513000000003,10242.804],List[-38136.229999999996,-22834.871,10242.805],List[-35650.208,-26555.513000000003,10242.804],List[-34109.07,-26862.032,9549.994],List[-35650.208,-26555.513000000003,9549.994],List[-32567.932,-26555.513000000003,9549.994],List[-31261.469,-25682.528000000002,9549.992],List[-31558.954,-25384.981,9549.992],List[-36956.726,-25682.528000000002,9549.994],List[-30388.483,-21293.734,9549.992],List[-31261.467,-25682.528000000002,10242.802],List[-30388.483,-24376.009,9549.992],List[-30388.481,-24376.009,10242.802],List[-37829.712,-24376.009,9549.994],List[-36956.726,-25682.528000000002,10242.804],List[-37829.712,-24376.009,10242.804],List[-38136.229999999996,-22834.871,9549.994999999999],List[-31558.954,-20284.761,9549.992],List[-37829.712,-21293.734,9549.994],List[-37829.712,-21293.734,10242.804],List[-36956.726,-19987.276,9549.994],List[-36956.726,-19987.276,10242.804],List[-31261.469,-19987.276,9549.992],List[-31261.467,-19987.276,10242.802],List[-30388.481,-21293.734,10242.802],List[-32567.932,-19114.29,9549.994],List[-34109.07,-18807.711000000003,9549.994],List[-32567.932,-19114.29,10242.804],List[-35650.208,-19114.29,9549.994],List[-35650.208,-19114.29,10242.804],List[-34109.07,-18807.711000000003,10242.804],List[-30081.902,-22834.871,10242.802],List[-30081.902,-22834.871,9549.992]],List[Polygon[List[List[1,2,3],List[4,1,3],List[5,4,6],List[7,1,5],List[8,5,6],List[8,7,5],List[9,8,10],List[11,8,9],List[8,2,7],List[11,13,8],List[13,12,8],List[8,6,10],List[9,10,15],List[10,17,15],List[6,16,10],List[3,17,16],List[16,4,3],List[15,3,18],List[9,15,18],List[19,18,20],List[18,21,20],List[20,22,19],List[20,23,22],List[19,22,24],List[11,19,24],List[11,9,19],List[24,26,11],List[27,24,28],List[27,25,24],List[24,30,28],List[22,30,24],List[30,32,28],List[22,31,30],List[31,23,3],List[31,3,32],List[28,29,27],List[3,29,32],List[3,25,29],List[23,21,3],List[26,25,3],List[33,26,3],List[11,33,34],List[34,14,13],List[14,33,3],List[12,14,3],List[11,34,13],List[2,12,3],List[4,5,1],List[1,7,2],List[2,8,12],List[12,13,14],List[17,10,16],List[16,6,4],List[3,15,17],List[18,19,9],List[21,18,3],List[23,20,21],List[26,24,25],List[25,27,29],List[32,30,31],List[31,22,23],List[29,28,32],List[33,11,26],List[14,34,33]]]],List[Rule[Boxed,False],Rule[Lighting,List[List["Ambient",GrayLevel[0.45]],List["Directional",GrayLevel[0.3],ImageScaled[List[2,0,2]]],List["Directional",GrayLevel[0.33],ImageScaled[List[2,2,2]]],List["Directional",GrayLevel[0.3],ImageScaled[List[0,2,2]]]]]]]

g = BoundingRegion[mesh, "FastCylinder"]
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], g, mesh}]
```

The result of `MinOrientedCuboid` is also bad in this instance, so sad.

```
pts={{-1.8617080450057983`,0.25396791100502014`,1.8142945766448975`},{-0.5651696920394897`,1.6006159782409668`,2.525299072265625`},{-0.4256100654602051`,1.4630788564682007`,2.531304359436035`},{-1.7221484184265137`,0.11643075942993164`,1.8202998638153076`},{-0.29905974864959717`,1.3192646503448486`,2.57292103767395`},{-1.5955981016159058`,-0.02738344669342041`,1.8619166612625122`},{-0.1903820037841797`,1.1747002601623535`,2.648550033569336`},{-1.4869203567504883`,-0.17194777727127075`,1.9375455379486084`},{-0.10375344753265381`,1.0349411964416504`,2.7552847862243652`},{-1.4002916812896729`,-0.3117068409919739`,2.0442802906036377`},{-0.042502760887145996`,0.9053583741188049`,2.889023542404175`},{-1.3390411138534546`,-0.44128966331481934`,2.1780190467834473`},{-0.008984088897705078`,0.7909313440322876`,3.0446269512176514`},{-1.3055224418640137`,-0.5557167530059814`,2.333622455596924`},{-0.004485607147216797`,0.6960576772689819`,3.2161149978637695`},{-1.3010239601135254`,-0.6505904197692871`,2.505110740661621`},{-0.029179930686950684`,0.624383270740509`,3.396897792816162`},{-1.3257181644439697`,-0.7222647666931152`,2.6858935356140137`},{-0.08211815357208252`,0.5786625146865845`,3.5800278186798096`},{-1.3786565065383911`,-0.7679855823516846`,2.869023323059082`},{-0.16126596927642822`,0.560652494430542`,3.758467674255371`},{-1.4578043222427368`,-0.785995602607727`,3.0474631786346436`},{-0.2635817527770996`,0.5710452198982239`,3.9253594875335693`},{-1.5601201057434082`,-0.7756028175354004`,3.214354991912842`},{-0.38513338565826416`,0.6094413995742798`,4.0742902755737305`},{-1.6816718578338623`,-0.7372066974639893`,3.363285779953003`},{-0.5212500095367432`,0.6743654012680054`,4.199536323547363`},{-1.8177883625030518`,-0.6722826957702637`,3.4885318279266357`},{-0.6667004823684692`,0.7633222937583923`,4.2962846755981445`},{-1.9632388353347778`,-0.5833258628845215`,3.585280179977417`},{-0.8158954381942749`,0.8728935718536377`,4.3608174324035645`},{-2.112433910369873`,-0.47375452518463135`,3.649812698364258`},{-0.9631012678146362`,0.9988683462142944`,4.390654563903809`},{-2.2596397399902344`,-0.3477797508239746`,3.679649829864502`},{-1.102660894393921`,1.1364054679870605`,4.384649276733398`},{-2.3991992473602295`,-0.2102426290512085`,3.673644542694092`},{-1.2292112112045288`,1.2802196741104126`,4.343032360076904`},{-2.525749683380127`,-0.06642842292785645`,3.6320278644561768`},{-1.3378889560699463`,1.4247839450836182`,4.267403602600098`},{-2.634427309036255`,0.0781359076499939`,3.556398868560791`},{-1.4245176315307617`,1.5645430088043213`,4.16066837310791`},{-2.7210559844970703`,0.21789497137069702`,3.4496641159057617`},{-1.48576819896698`,1.6941258907318115`,4.02692985534668`},{-2.782306671142578`,0.34747785329818726`,3.315925359725952`},{-1.519286870956421`,1.8085529804229736`,3.871326446533203`},{-2.8158252239227295`,0.4619048833847046`,3.1603219509124756`},{-1.5237853527069092`,1.9034266471862793`,3.699838161468506`},{-2.8203237056732178`,0.5567785501480103`,2.9888339042663574`},{-1.4990911483764648`,1.9751009941101074`,3.5190553665161133`},{-2.7956295013427734`,0.6284529566764832`,2.808051109313965`},{-1.4461528062820435`,2.0208218097686768`,3.335925579071045`},{-2.7426910400390625`,0.6741737127304077`,2.6249210834503174`},{-1.3670049905776978`,2.0388317108154297`,3.1574857234954834`},{-2.663543224334717`,0.6921837329864502`,2.446481227874756`},{-1.2646892070770264`,2.0284390449523926`,2.990593910217285`},{-2.561227560043335`,0.6817910075187683`,2.2795894145965576`},{-1.1431374549865723`,1.9900429248809814`,2.841663122177124`},{-2.439675807952881`,0.6433948278427124`,2.1306586265563965`},{-1.0070209503173828`,1.9251189231872559`,2.716417074203491`},{-2.3035593032836914`,0.5784708261489868`,2.0054125785827637`},{-0.8615704774856567`,1.8361620903015137`,2.61966872215271`},{-2.158108711242676`,0.48951393365859985`,1.908664345741272`},{-0.7123755216598511`,1.7265907526016235`,2.555136203765869`},{-2.008913993835449`,0.3799426853656769`,1.844131588935852`}};
```

`Graphics3D[{BoundingRegion[pts,"MinOrientedCuboid"],Red,Point/@pts}]`
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think there is a bug in "MinEllipsoid". Please report it to support@wolfram.com

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/236047/6648

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/212554/6648

Comment: @DanielHuber  Not only the option of `MinEllipsoid`, also `FastStadium`,`MinOrientedCuboid` maybe.