# What's the problem of RegionFit in this task of fitting a cylinder

Tags: regions, mesh

```
mesh = MeshRegion[
   List[List[-34109.07, -26862.032, 10242.804], 
    List[-32567.932, -26555.513000000003, 10242.804], 
    List[-38136.229999999996, -22834.871, 10242.805], 
    List[-35650.208, -26555.513000000003, 10242.804], 
    List[-34109.07, -26862.032, 9549.994], 
    List[-35650.208, -26555.513000000003, 9549.994], 
    List[-32567.932, -26555.513000000003, 9549.994], 
    List[-31261.469, -25682.528000000002, 9549.992], 
    List[-31558.954, -25384.981, 9549.992], 
    List[-36956.726, -25682.528000000002, 9549.994], 
    List[-30388.483, -21293.734, 9549.992], 
    List[-31261.467, -25682.528000000002, 10242.802], 
    List[-30388.483, -24376.009, 9549.992], 
    List[-30388.481, -24376.009, 10242.802], 
    List[-37829.712, -24376.009, 9549.994], 
    List[-36956.726, -25682.528000000002, 10242.804], 
    List[-37829.712, -24376.009, 10242.804], 
    List[-38136.229999999996, -22834.871, 9549.994999999999], 
    List[-31558.954, -20284.761, 9549.992], 
    List[-37829.712, -21293.734, 9549.994], 
    List[-37829.712, -21293.734, 10242.804], 
    List[-36956.726, -19987.276, 9549.994], 
    List[-36956.726, -19987.276, 10242.804], 
    List[-31261.469, -19987.276, 9549.992], 
    List[-31261.467, -19987.276, 10242.802], 
    List[-30388.481, -21293.734, 10242.802], 
    List[-32567.932, -19114.29, 9549.994], 
    List[-34109.07, -18807.711000000003, 9549.994], 
    List[-32567.932, -19114.29, 10242.804], 
    List[-35650.208, -19114.29, 9549.994], 
    List[-35650.208, -19114.29, 10242.804], 
    List[-34109.07, -18807.711000000003, 10242.804], 
    List[-30081.902, -22834.871, 10242.802], 
    List[-30081.902, -22834.871, 9549.992]], 
   List[Polygon[
     List[List[1, 2, 3], List[4, 1, 3], List[5, 4, 6], List[7, 1, 5], 
      List[8, 5, 6], List[8, 7, 5], List[9, 8, 10], List[11, 8, 9], 
      List[8, 2, 7], List[11, 13, 8], List[13, 12, 8], List[8, 6, 10],
       List[9, 10, 15], List[10, 17, 15], List[6, 16, 10], 
      List[3, 17, 16], List[16, 4, 3], List[15, 3, 18], 
      List[9, 15, 18], List[19, 18, 20], List[18, 21, 20], 
      List[20, 22, 19], List[20, 23, 22], List[19, 22, 24], 
      List[11, 19, 24], List[11, 9, 19], List[24, 26, 11], 
      List[27, 24, 28], List[27, 25, 24], List[24, 30, 28], 
      List[22, 30, 24], List[30, 32, 28], List[22, 31, 30], 
      List[31, 23, 3], List[31, 3, 32], List[28, 29, 27], 
      List[3, 29, 32], List[3, 25, 29], List[23, 21, 3], 
      List[26, 25, 3], List[33, 26, 3], List[11, 33, 34], 
      List[34, 14, 13], List[14, 33, 3], List[12, 14, 3], 
      List[11, 34, 13], List[2, 12, 3], List[4, 5, 1], List[1, 7, 2], 
      List[2, 8, 12], List[12, 13, 14], List[17, 10, 16], 
      List[16, 6, 4], List[3, 15, 17], List[18, 19, 9], 
      List[21, 18, 3], List[23, 20, 21], List[26, 24, 25], 
      List[25, 27, 29], List[32, 30, 31], List[31, 22, 23], 
      List[29, 28, 32], List[33, 11, 26], List[14, 34, 33]]]], 
   List[Rule[Boxed, False], 
    Rule[Lighting, 
     List[List["Ambient", GrayLevel[0.45]], 
      List["Directional", GrayLevel[0.3], ImageScaled[List[2, 0, 2]]],
       List["Directional", GrayLevel[0.33], 
       ImageScaled[List[2, 2, 2]]], 
      List["Directional", GrayLevel[0.3], 
       ImageScaled[List[0, 2, 2]]]]]]];
```

---

RegionFit is a new function in version 13.1.

I want to bounding a cylinder like in this post [Why BoundingRegion so weak in FastCylinder option?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/272778/6648)

Since it has some problems, I'm trying to use `RegionFit`.

I get some ridiculous results.

Question1:
Can anyone fit this cylinder via using RegionFit like that in the example page.

Question2:
Can anyone fit this cylinder via using any `Mathematica` functions?

Question3:
Can anyone fit this cylinder via other softwares show the weakness of `Mathematica`?

[image]

[image]