# Bug of RandomPoint or Bug of Region?

Tags: warning-messages, regions, mesh

Mathematica 13.1 on Mac

In the help page of RandomPoint, it says:

***RandomPoint can generate random points for any RegionQ region that is also ConstantRegionQ.***

The data of mesh is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272779/whats-the-problem-of-regionfit-in-this-cylinder)

```
meshConvex = ConvexHullMesh@mesh
RandomPoint[mesh,100]
```

The error report (message `CompiledFunction::cfta`) is in the picture below. So where goes wrong.

After triangulate the `meshConvex`, it works fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I noticed that `ConvexHullMesh` returns a `BoundaryMeshRegion`, whereas `mesh` and `TriangulateMesh@ConvexHullMesh@mesh` are both a `MeshRegion`. However, `RandomPoint` should work on `BoundaryMeshRegion` objects, so I am not sure if that is reason enough for the behavior you see. By the way, the behavior is the same on MMA 12.3.1 on Win10-64.

Comment: @MarcoB  RandomPoint can generate random points for any RegionQ region that is also ConstantRegionQ.

Comment: Some ConvexHullMesh meshes are OK, some are not  @MarcoB

Comment: I agree that this is unexpected behavior. It's hard to say where the problem lies, if in RandomPoint or in ConvexHullMesh or in a combination of the two, but I think you should report this to Wolfram Support.